# Laravel 8 Trying to get property 'type' of non-object error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make it so I can as admin impersonate users in my app. I get this error

```
Trying to get property 'type' of non-object
```

on this line

```
    if($user->type !== 1)  //1 for type admin
```

in someUserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Models\User;

class someUserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $id = Auth::id();
    $user = User::find($id);

    //echo '<pre>ID:'.$id.' - '.print_r($user,1); die();

    if($user->type !== 1)  //1 for type admin
    {
        echo ' error not admin (nice try!).';
        die();
    }
}

public function impersonate($id)
    {       
        Auth::logout(); // for end current session
        Auth::loginUsingId($id);

        return redirect()->to('dashboard');
    }
}
```

route web.php

```
Route::get('/impersonate/{id}', [someUserController::class, 'impersonate']);

Route::get('dashboard', function () {

    $id = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id();
    $user = \App\Models\User::find($id);

    //echo '<pre>'.print_r($user,1); die();

    if(!$user->active) return redirect('404-page');


    switch($user->type)
    {
        case 1: return redirect('x-url-dashboard-1'); break;
        case 2: return redirect('x-url-dashboard-2'); break;
        case 3: return redirect('x-url-dashboard-3'); break;
    }
```

This is the link in my blade file.

```
<a href="{{ url('impersonate') }}/{{ $user->id }}" class="btn btn-success">Enter as {{$user->name}}</a>
```

Comment: you don't have access to the session in the constructor of a controller so that also means no auth

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `User::find($id);` is returning null, indicating that there is no user in your database with the nominated id.

In any case, you'll find it easier to use `Auth::user()` instead, as with your current code you are make two database calls for no real reason.

- You're already authenticated so it knows who you are
- Don't need to find the user by id, you already have it.

To fix your issue, check that the `$id` is what you think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to what @Jason explained, you could try something like below:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    if(Auth::user()->type !== 1)
    {
        abort(403);
    }
}
```